# Authenicated USers Permission overides Active Directory Security Group

Tags: permissions

I have a site in my SharePoint 2010 Intranet that has READ ACCESS for NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users. I also have an active directory security group applied to the permissions for that site that has CONTRIBUTE ACCESS.

For some reason the READ access is overriding the CONTRIBUTE access for the users in the AD Group. So the contributors can't upload etc. Does anyone know why this might occur?

If I create a SharePoint Group and add the users manually by name then everything works as expected.

Any thoughts or suggestions gratefully received.
Thanks,
Nigel

Comment: That shouldn't be the case, are you certain the library they are trying to upload to has the correct permissions? It doesn't have broken permissions inheritance does it?

Comment: Hi, The site has broken inheritance permissions from the parent site as it needs different permissions from the parent.